# Tabs problem in Tablet fragment

Tags: android, tablet, fragment

Like for list view there is ListFragment.So is there anyway to so that i can put tabs inside one fragment like TabActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TabHost` inside a fragment, see the Google IO app, it does this for the session details fragment:

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/SessionDetailFragment.java